# Launch configuration biffviewer references non-existing project

Tags: java

I added some remote repository to my project and it seemed to have messed up my launch configurations.

While trying to debug my my code I get the following error:

> Launching BiffViewer has encountered a problem : Launch configuration biffviewer references non-existing project.

This is one of the class that I am trying to debug:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.package.chestionar.controller.LoginController;

/**
 * This code was edited or generated using CloudGarden's Jigloo
 * SWT/Swing GUI Builder, which is free for non-commercial
 * use. If Jigloo is being used commercially (ie, by a corporation,
 * company or business for any purpose whatever) then you
 * should purchase a license for each developer using Jigloo.
 * Please visit www.cloudgarden.com for details.
 * Use of Jigloo implies acceptance of these licensing terms.
 * A COMMERCIAL LICENSE HAS NOT BEEN PURCHASED FOR
 * THIS MACHINE, SO JIGLOO OR THIS CODE CANNOT BE USED
 * LEGALLY FOR ANY CORPORATE OR COMMERCIAL PURPOSE.
 */
public class JLogin extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    private JLabel lblUtilizator;
    private JLabel lblParola;
    private JButton btLogin;
    private JLabel lblMesaj;
    private JPasswordField txtParola;
    private JButton btInchide;
    private JTextField txtUtilizator;
    private LoginController loginController = new LoginController();
    //daca se logeaza cu success, session e true
    private boolean session = false;
    //numele utilizatorului;
    private String utilizator;

    /**
    * Auto-generated main method to display this JDialog
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JLogin inst = new JLogin(frame);
                inst.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public JLogin(JFrame frame) {
        super(frame,"Loginn");
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            setModal(true);
            {
                lblUtilizator = new JLabel();
                getContentPane().add(lblUtilizator);
                lblUtilizator.setText("Utilizatorrr");
                lblUtilizator.setBounds(48, 35, 90, 16);
            }
            {
                txtUtilizator = new JTextField();
                getContentPane().add(txtUtilizator);
                txtUtilizator.setBounds(150, 32, 171, 23);
            }
            {
                lblParola = new JLabel();
                getContentPane().add(lblParola);
                lblParola.setText("Parola");
                lblParola.setBounds(48, 64, 48, 16);
            }
            {
                btLogin = new JButton();
                getContentPane().add(btLogin);
                btLogin.setText("Login");
                btLogin.setBounds(37, 130, 80, 23);
                btLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        try {
                            utilizator = txtUtilizator.getText();
                            session = loginController.login(txtUtilizator.getText(), txtParola.getText());
                            dispose();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            session = false;
                            lblMesaj.setText(e.getMessage());
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
            {
                btInchide = new JButton();
                getContentPane().add(btInchide);
                btInchide.setText("Inchide");
                btInchide.setBounds(237, 130, 84, 23);
                btInchide.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        session = false;
                        dispose();
                    }
                });
            }
            {
                lblMesaj = new JLabel();
                getContentPane().add(lblMesaj);
                lblMesaj.setBounds(48, 103, 273, 16);
                lblMesaj.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255,0,0));
            }
            {
                txtParola = new JPasswordField();
                getContentPane().add(txtParola);
                txtParola.setBounds(150, 61, 171, 23);
            }
            this.setSize(389, 202);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public boolean isValid() {
        return session;
    }
    public String getUtilizator() {
        return utilizator;
    }
}
```

I read some similar questions that were answered before and it seems that I need to go to `Run Configuration` and find the launcher that's giving me trouble.

I don't know what to do exactly so I need some help. Can someone help me?
If this questions seems silly sorry, but I am trying from last night to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It gives error saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type

at

```
newpackage.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:16)
```